# HTML - How to add my header to every page without really adding code

Tags: html, css, dynamic, header

I am looking for an simple and effective way to add an html header to every page in my website.

I currently have the header in a separate html and css file. This way it is already fully separate.

Comment: Look into either using JavaScript to add things to the page, PHP `include` (or similar in other backend languages), React (or similar frameworks) - all these can be used for that purpose

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done using plain HTML. You'll need some kind of templating engine like `EJS` or a framework like [Hugo](https://gohugo.io) or a javascript framework/library like `React`, `Vue`, or `Svelte`.